# How to set multiple homepages in Firefox

Tags: firefox, automation, productivity, homepage

I have three different websites that I check daily. I want to set all of these sites as homepages so that they'll be loaded as soon as I start Firefox, preventing me from having to navigate to each one manually.

**How do I do this?**

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate because it's asked exclusively about Firefox. I hadn't come across that question or any other when searching for how to do this myself, and that's likely due to the more general way it's worded. When people go searching for this stuff, they tend to do so using more specific search terms, including the name of their browser and keywords like "homepage", and I feel like that's a good reason to keep this question open.

Answer (score 1):

1. In a single Firefox window, navigate to all of the websites that you want to set as homepages, making sure to arrange them in the order that you want them to be opened when starting Firefox.
2. In the Menu bar, navigate to **Tools > Options** - or enter  `about:preferences` into the address bar.
3. Click **Use Current Pages** to set all currently open tabs as homepages.

[image: screenshot of Firefox Options/preferences menu]

**Alternatively**, you can do this *without* navigating to each of your homepages by entering the links to them manually - simply paste the URLs into the *Home Page* field, separating them using the pipe `|` character, and then close the *Options* tab.

The next time you open Firefox, you'll be greeted by multiple homepages.